# checking for evenness/oddness of an integer efficiently

Tags: c++, function, conditional-statements

I have a mathematical function, which depends on three variables {n, a and b} that are given by

{a = n+1, b=n} when n is even

{b = n+1, a=n} when n is odd

My function is called *many* times, with various n. Is there an efficient way to implement this? I'm thinking that a `switch` and `if` statement might not be that efficient in the long run..

EDIT: Here is a minimal example:

```
void func(int n)
{
    int a, b;
    if(!(n%2))
    {
        a=n+1;
        b=n;
    }
    else
    {
        a=n;
        b=n+1;
    }
    //continue ...
}
```

Comment: "I'm thinking that (...)" Does that matter? How long would it take to implement and test such a simple solution and learn whether it is or not efficient *enough*?

Comment: And anyway, how else would you implement decisons if not using if?

Comment: @Boris `n` will always be positive

Comment: I suppose `unsigned int` will be more clear at this function.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As long as the number system used is two's complement (that is, -1 == ~0), you can use this:

```
  int odd = n & 1;
  a = n + !odd;    // Adds one if n is even
  b = n + odd;     // adds one if n is odd.
```

This solution avoids both `% 2`, which, even for `2` can become a little more than `& 1`, as well as avoiding the if. It should be significantly faster than the `if` solution, and probably a little better than the `% 2`.

If the number system isn't known to be two's complement (and numbers can be negative), this would avoid the if:

```
 int odd = !!(n % 2);  // using !! to ensure 0 or 1 value.
 a = n + !odd;
 b = n + odd;
```

which is the same logic as my first code, but avoids relying on two's complement. Although I'm not aware of any general purpose processor that isn't two's complement that is in production today (or even has been in production in the last 20 or so years - no doubt someone will tell me that I'm wrong and some popular models are still being made...).

As always with performance, make sure you know what is a bottleneck, and only "mess" with the code if it actually is something that ends up in the top 10. And measure the new code as well as the old one to make sure the new code is actually an improvement.

Comment: common subexpression elimination: `auto p = (n & 1); a = n + !p; b = n + p;`

Comment: @TemplateRex: why would you do the work of the compiler manually?

Comment: Of course, any compiler worth its salt will optimize `n % 2` into `n & 1` iff this optimization is valid.

Comment: @riv it's not just for efficiency, but also Don't Repeat Yourself. putting the `(n&1)` inside a separate variable also allows you to document it, and change it to something else (perhaps some other boolean expression) later if you want.

Comment: @MatthieuM. Try it - because `%2` is defined differently for negative numbers than `&1`, it has to "fix up" the negative numbers with a couple of extra instructions, compared to `& 1` - it doesn't use a divide instruction, but it uses some extra code. If all you want is whether the number is odd or even, and with one is as efficient as you can get.

Comment: @MatthieuM. Very true. All sorts of bit twiddling  stuff with compile time constants are optimized, even by VC++. Multiplication by constant is turned into shifts, modulo into ands.

Comment: @MatsPetersson: ah right, that's because C99 chose to implement the *remainder* while in mathematics we use the *modulo* :(

Comment: Yes, I've just added a `!!` plus comment to the "use % 2" solution.

Answer (score 1):

The following code will tell whether a is even or odd:

```
if(a%2==0)
{
    a = n+1;
    b=n;
}
else
{
    b = n+1;
    a=n;
}
```

This is called the "modulus" or "modulo" operator, and returns the remainder of the left input divided by the right input. If the remainder is 0 when a is divided by two, then two must go evenly into it and thus a is even. Otherwise, it is odd.

Comment: I'm pretty sure OP already knows this, as they used modulus in the question.  The question is more about the efficiency of an `if ... else` rather than "how do I tell if a number is even or odd?"

Comment: I wrote that answer before the author edited their post to include that, but okay.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the following:

```
int a = n|1;
int b = (n+1)&~1;
```

gcc -O3 outputs (n is stored in register eax)

```
mov edx, eax
add eax, 1
or  edx, 1    //a is in edx
and eax, -2   //b is in eax
```

While using

```
int a = n + 1 - (n&1);
int b = n + (n&1);
```

gives (n is stored in edx)

```
mov ecx, edx
mov eax, edx
and ecx, 1
or  eax, 1
add edx, ecx
```

and

```
int a = n + !(n&1);
int b = n + (n&1);
```

gives

```
mov eax, edx
and eax, 1
mov ecx, eax
xor ecx, 1
lea eax, [eax+edx*2]
```

The first variant has (at least using gcc) one instruction less than the other variants. Nevertheless, depending on your compiler, you have to profile your code.

Answer (score 0):

```
b = n + (n & 1)
a = n + n + 1 - b
```

Comment: Is that not more complicated than `!(n & 1)`?

Comment: I'm getting 7 instructions for `a = n + !(n & 1)` and 5 for `b = n + n + 1 - a`, don't think it really matters though.

Answer (score 0):

Try this which is without if:

```
a = n + (n + 1) % 2
b = n + n % 2
```

But I'm not sure if the performance is going to be any different. Measure the performance before judging it.

Answer (score 0):

You could try this, but you'd have to profile to see whether its performance is better/worse:

```
int *p[] = {&a, &b};
*p[n % 2] = n + 1;
*p[1 - (n % 2)] = n;
```

Comment: You're missing a level of indirection. And anyway, then why not `& 1` instead of `% 2`, if we try to second guess the compiler?

Comment: @H2CO3 Fixed indirection, thanks. There was an answer with `& 1` already when I posted, no other reason, really. I see this pretty much as a "brainstorming" question, anyway.

Answer (score 0):

As one more way :

```
int a, b;
a = b = n;
{
    int p = n & 1;
    b += p;
    a += p ^ 1;
}
```

Here:

- Mass copy to `a`, `b`.
- Help compiler to detect less scope of `p`.
- `&` in one place.